# Cortona3D and X3DOM

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I have a really really big *.wrl file which I also have in *.x3d and the point is to visualize the 3D file in a web browser.

For this, I use X3DOM. It works well with an inline.
The problem is, that when using X3DOM, when I visualize the 3D object (made on Catia), it has a very very low FPS. Navigation is impossible.

But, when reading the same file in *.wrl with Cortona3D Player, it is smooth... So it's not really a problem of resources I suppose but maybe a matter of parallel programming ?

I'm quite lost on this topic and I would like some help because displaying the file on a web browser with the possibility JavaScript offers is really important for my project.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of your geometry? Did you try one of X3DOM's binary formats? They can be used to display pretty huge geometries.

Comment: Got 28,320 Nodes; 19,969 Shapes and Draws; 707,399 Points and 234,460 Tris...
Binary formats ? How do I use it ?
I saw it was used for the example of the Sienna's Cathedral which works well !

Comment: I rather guess that the amount of nodes and shapes might be too much in your case. Can you try to reduce them e.g. using aopt http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=532 it also provides binary output formats.

Comment: you might want to use GPAC. I managed to open huge files with it. http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/

Comment: I used aopt to binary compress the files, it works really well !

Answer (score 0):

At best you need to collapse your geometry from 28320 nodes to like < 500 (just a guess at a good number but the less the better).

Of course there's a limit to the number of polygons a GPU can draw at a reasonable speed but there's also an overhead for every draw call. Each node in your X3DOM scene represents at least 1 draw call, more if there are shadows.

So for example a building made one node per brick will draw much much much slower than a building made out of a single node with all the bricks merged into one mesh